# Find first visible cell below and get reference

Tags: excel, visible, autofilter, vba

I'm trying to select first **visible** cell after header while using autofilter.

```
If First.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
Range("A1").Select
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

But in next step I need to operate with this cell, so I need its row and column number. How could I  get it? (without using lastrow and lastcolumn)

Answer (score 2):

You could try this (first three lines used as sample code)

*Updated for user comment*

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = [a1:a10]
rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="4"
If rng1.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count > 1 Then
    Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1)
    MsgBox rng2.Address
End If
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't help me. I need way to operate with this cell in further code and .Address doesn't provide such opportunity

Comment: You can adjust @brettdj's code to return what you'd like: try ending that line with `.Row`, or `.Column` or `.Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt -- "But in next step I need to operate with this cell, **so I need its row and column number. How could I get it?** (without using lastrow and lastcolumn)"  Hence, my my answer.  Please explain how this does not provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through column A too:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughVisibleColA()

Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim FilterRange As Range, ColumnARange As Range, _
    Cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

'set worksheet for easy reference
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'identify the ranges for our filter and loop action
LastRow = MySheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = MySheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set FilterRange = Range(MySheet.Cells(1, 1), MySheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
Set ColumnARange = Range(MySheet.Cells(1, 1), MySheet.Cells(LastRow, 1))

'apply filter: in this example, filter column A for values >4
FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">4"

'loop through the visible cells in our column A range
For Each Cell In ColumnARange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Cell.Row <> 1 Then 'skip the header row
        MsgBox ("We're in row " & Cell.Row & " and column " & Cell.Column)
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Application.Sendkeys "{DOWN}", True` then read `Selection.Address`